# Record file m4a doesn't upload to backend on android flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, file-upload, m4a

so I was trying to upload files (png, pdf etc) to backend endpoint and it works on both android and iOS and there's a recorder in the app it returns m4a files when I try to upload the m4a files using the same function it works on iOS and the file gets uploaded but it doesn't work on android
Do you know why is that?

Here's the recorder code:

```
  final recorder = Record();
  record() async {
    bool recording = await recorder.isRecording();
    if (recording) {
      String? path = await recorder.stop();
      await recorder.dispose();
      if (path != null) {
        attachments ??= [];
        File file = File(Platform.isIOS ? path.substring(7) : path);
        bool fileExits = await file.exists();
        if (fileExits) {
          attachments?.add(file);
        }
        setState(() {
          isRecording = false;
        });
      }
    } else {
      if (await recorder.hasPermission()) {
        setState(() {
          isRecording = true;
        });
        await recorder.start(
          encoder: AudioEncoder.aacLc,
          bitRate: 128000,
        );
        await Future.delayed(const Duration(minutes: 3), () async {
          if (await recorder.isRecording()) {
            String? path = await recorder.stop();
            await recorder.dispose();
            if (path != null) {
              attachments ??= [];
              File file = File(Platform.isIOS ? path.substring(7) : path);
              bool fileExits = await file.exists();
              if (fileExits) {
                attachments?.add(file);
              }
              setState(() {
                isRecording = false;
              });
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

Here's the function:

```
static Future<String?> uploadFile(File file, String token) async {
    // final fileLength = await image.length();
    String? imageURL;
    var request =
        http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(APIEndPoints.uploadFiles));
    request.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer $token';
    request.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
    request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('file', file.path));
    http.StreamedResponse res = await request.send();
    String responseBody = await res.stream.bytesToString();
    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      imageURL = '${APIEndPoints.baseUrl}/${jsonDecode(responseBody)['url']}';
    }
    print(res.statusCode);
    print(responseBody);
    return imageURL;
  }
```

Comment: check path first
the only difference you have is path. Substring(7) for iOS

Comment: Yeah I did that because iOS has this file/// before the real path but in android it has the actual path directly and I’m checking if the path exists first and it does the package saves it in the cache folder I even tried to move it to another path but still it doesn’t get uploaded

Comment: then try to save the file to a temporary directory. that's how I do it.
RecordPlugin( https://pub.dev/packages/record ) has options for it

Comment: You mean the path option? I tried it and it gives me the same error

Comment: with file name or just folder. I include file name as well.
actually I will just write how I do it

Comment: await recorder.start(
          path: '${directory?.path}/${DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch}.m4a',
          encoder: AudioEncoder.aacLc,
          bitRate: 128000,
        ); this is how I tried it

Comment: now i see why...

Comment: What’s the issue?

Comment: I checked my code and found that you need some short delay until the record starts and stops and save file. I posted an answer with the code and how I do it

Answer (score 0):

I use the [Record Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/record) and will show you how I do it.
I save the file in the temporary directory.

You get temporary directory with [Path Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider).

```
final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
```

Then use the dir and set path for the temporary file.

```
await _recorder.start(
  const RecordConfig(),
  path: '${tempDir.path}/temp-audio.m4a',
);
```

and when the audio stops, you use the path from the recorder.

```
final path = await _recorder.stop();
```

Also, for when recorder starts and stops, I wait for about 400 milliseconds.
I found that there is some delay, which I didn't delve into yet.
The full code is below for your reference.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package: record/record.dart';

class RecorderWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const RecorderWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<RecorderWidget> createState() => _RecorderWidgetState();
}

class _RecorderWidgetState extends State<RecorderWidget> {
  final _recorder = AudioRecorder();

  bool _isRecording = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _recorder.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> _start() async {
    try {
      if (await _recorder.hasPermission()) {
        final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
        await _recorder.start(
          const RecordConfig(),
          path: '${tempDir.path}/temp-audio.m4a',
        );
        // Just wait a while until recorder is properly loaded
        await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 400));
        bool isRecording = await _recorder.isRecording();
        setState(() {
          _isRecording = isRecording;
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    }
  }

  Future<void> _stop() async {
    final path = await _recorder.stop();
    setState(() => _isRecording = false);
    if (path != null) {
      // some delay just to make sure that file is saved properly
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 400));
      // do something with path
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // display recorder stuff
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: But where do you get the AudioRecorder and RecordConfig from ? it's not in the record package

Comment: oh you are using old package... I have updated my package version to 5.0.1

Comment: I’m using the latest version 5.0.1 too  tried the example code of the package and when trying to send the file to the api endpoint it gives me the same error too

Comment: what's the error exactly?